# MSAL access token do not have claims - V2.0 endpoint B2C

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have created two applications in my Azure AD B2C tenant ( XXXX.onmicrosoft.com )

1. Front end - Angular 7 ( Configured as `postman` )
2. Backend - Web API - .net core 2.1 ( Configured as `childcare.webapi`  )

[image]

Web API project is straight forward .NET Core 2.2 API project, created it using VS template.

appsettings.js file looks like

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {       
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/",
    "ClientId": "APPLICATOIN-ID-OF-childcare.webapi",
    "Domain": "XXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_Signup"
  }
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Startup code looks like :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
                services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
                services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }
```

`Postmanapp` has given access to `childcare.webapi` scopes

[image]

Next, I have edited default 'B2C_1_Signup' policy and added 'Facebook' identity provider.  I ran this user flow from azure portal to grab the access token which my `postman` app can use for accessing '`childcare.webapi`'

[image]

so far so good.  I got back an access token which has scope '`user_impersonation`'  Below is how token looks like...

```
{
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{GUID}/v2.0/",      
  "aud": "childcare.api APPLICATION ID",
  ...
  "idp": "facebook.com",
  ...
  "tfp": "B2C_1_Signup",      
  "scp": "user_impersonation",
  "azp": "postman app APPLICATION ID",      
}
```

With this access token I was successfully able to invoke `childcare.api` endpoint using postman application.

[image]

**Question**

Now I want to grab same access token in my Angular 6 application.  I am using popular library `"@azure/msal-angular": "^0.1.2"`

Below is my MsalModule configuration.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: 'POSTMAN APP CLIENT ID',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/XXXX.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_Signup', // working     
      validateAuthority: false,
      consentScopes:
      [
        'https://xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/childcare/user_impersonation'
      ]
```

and below is login method.

```
public login(): void {
    this.authService.loginPopup (['https://XXX.onmicrosoft.com/childcare/user_impersonation']);
}
```

I was able to grab the toke but it was not valid for accessing childcare.webapi
It returned me 404.  When I examine the token carefully, its missing `user_impersonation` scope.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/435) regarding missing support for a new b2clogin.com domain.  But one user ( Sakta ) has commented we can use MSAL.js library with b2clogin.com domain.  But it didn't worked for me either.

Any pointers?

**Update 1** 
It looks like angular MSAL library is returning `id_token` not `access token`